# How to Add Element into a std::vector using std::any

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, stdany

I am working on a C++17 project and there i am using `std::any`. A minimal reproducible example is given below for reference explaining what i want to achieve.

```
#include <any>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
    
    std::any anything = vec;
    
   // anything.push_back(4);//i want to add an element into vector vec, using variable anything but this statement won't work

    
    std::cout<<std::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(anything).size()<<std::endl;//prints 3 
    std::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(anything).push_back(4);//this adds(push_back) element into rvalue
    std::cout<<std::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(anything).size()<<std::endl;//prints 3 but i want 4 
}
```

As can be seen in the above example, i have a `std::any` object and i am using `std::any_cast` to add element into the vector. I want to add the element into the actual(`lvalue`) vector named `vec` but instead, the element is added into an `rvalue`. **Is there a way to add element into the vector named `vec` using `std::any`.** If not then is there any other way of doing this like using `std::variant` or something else that i may not be aware of. I am looking for a way of doing this in any version of C++ like C++11 or C++17 etc.

In my actual project, there is requirement for storing object of any type. So i got the same problem there. And then realized what is wrong(namely, we are using `push_back` on an rvalue) and then i reduced the problem to a minimal reproducible example and am asking here.

Comment: why you use `std::any`? and why you're wrapping (actually copying) a existing `vector`?

Comment: it's OK, but why you still want to access old `vector`?

Comment: That doesn't look like a great design to me. Maybe you should consider refactoring your project instead?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to add an element to the vector `vec`, or the vector stored in `anything` which was copy-constructed from `vec`? You're using the two interchangeably but they are not the same object.

Comment: @Useless I want to add the element into the original vector `vec` and not in the copy that is stored inside `anything`

Comment: So you don't need `std::any` at all in that case. If you _do_ need `std::any` then I still don't understand your problem statement. Do you want `std::any` to store a reference to `vec` as one of the answers suggests? But if `vec` is still in scope, as in your example, you can still just append to it directly ...

Comment: @Useless Yes as i said this is just an example that i made to reproduce the problem. In this example there is no need for `std::any` i already know. I just wanted to know what i was doing wrong and was my analysis of what is going on correct or not. The answers showed me that i was wrong in my analysis and they correct/improved my understanding of `std::any` which is basically what i needed.

Comment: So when I asked you to clarify and you said you wanted to update the local scope vector `vec` ... that's _not_ what you really want to achieve? And if it's not, why do you keep talking about `vec` as if it's somehow relevant to your problem? This is all very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we are using push_back on an rvalue

No, that's not the problem. `any` stores a *copy* of what it is given. It doesn't reference some other object. It creates an object from what it is given. So even if you get a reference to the object in the `any`, it wouldn't be a reference to `vec` itself.

If you want to store a reference to an object in an `any`, you need to do so explicitly by storing either a pointer or a `reference_wrapper` to that object:

```
using ref_type = decltype(std::ref(vec));

std::any anything = std::ref(vec);

std::any_cast<ref_type>(anything).get().push_back(4);
```

Note that having an `any` which references an object is dangerous. If the `any` outlives the lifetime of the referenced object, you'll get bad things when you try to access the referenced object. This is part of why `any` stores copies by default.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a reference:

```
std::any_cast<std::vector<int>&>(anything).push_back(4);
//                            ^
```

Currently, you create copy with the `std::any_cast`.

Note:
As pointed by Nicol Bolas, that only avoid copy for the cast, but the copy of the initial `std::vector` into the `std::any` is not avoided.

Comment: That will give you a reference to the object in the `any`, but not a reference to `vec`.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any place in the asker's code where they think they're making a reference to `vec` but aren't. After making the copy into `anything`, all subsequent code acts on `anything` and none of it acts on `vec`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Indeed, but not sure if it would not be sufficient for OP.

Comment: @NathanPierson: "*There doesn't appear to be any place in the asker's code where they think they're making a reference to vec but aren't.*" The OP specifically says, "Is there a way to add element into the vector named vec using std::any". It's even in bold-face. The OP clearly doesn't know that `any` doesn't reference the original object by default.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh, yes, my bad.

Comment: @NicolBolas You wrote *That will give you a reference to the object in the `any`, but not a reference to `vec`.* As i understand it now, we have a *reference to a vector of int* inside `std::cast_any`. And so by using this reference i can change the actual vector `vec` which is a vector of `int`. My question is why did you wrote that this gives us a reference to the object in the `any` but not a reference to `vec` since the reference is referring to the vector `vec` which is what i wanted. *Did you mean that it will give a reference to the copy of `vec` that is stored in `any`?*

Comment: @AanchalSharma: My change still make `anything` a copy of `vec`, but allows to modify `anything`

Comment: Continued: Did you mean that it will give a reference to the copy of vec that is stored in any and not the actual vector `vec`?

Comment: @Jarod42 So this means that the element `4` is added to the vector stored inside `any` object instead of the actual vector `vec` right?

Comment: @AanchalSharma: "*Did you mean that it will give a reference to the copy of vec that is stored in any and not the actual vector vec?*" Yes, that is a rewarding of my literal words that you quoted. "object in the `any`" means exactly that.

Comment: @AanchalSharma: yes. `vec` is unmodified with my proposal, but you got expected output as vector stored in `anything` is 4 at the end.